# How do I check if a number evaluates to infinity?

Tags: javascript, infinity

I have a series of Javascript calculations that (only under IE) show Infinity depending on user choices.

How does one stop the word `Infinity` appearing and for example, show `0.0` instead?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
if (result == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || result == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
{
    // ...
}
```

You could possibly use the [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) function instead, depending on how you want to treat `NaN`. `isFinite` returns `false` if your number is `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` or `NaN`.

```
if (isFinite(result))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why use `Number.(POSITIVE|NEGATIVE)_INFINITY` instead of `-?Infinity` or `-?1/0`?

Comment: @Eli: The global `Infinity` property isn't read-only which means that it can be redefined: For example, `var x = 42; Infinity = 42; alert(x === Infinity);` displays *"true"*. (Admittedly that's an obscure case, and anyone who decides to redefine `Infinity`, `NaN` etc should expect odd things to happen.)

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `Number.(POSITIVE|NEGATIVE)_INFINITY` isn't read-only either, `Infinity` *is* read-only in strict mode. Also, what about the `-?1/0` case I presented to you? Anyways, you should almost always use `isFinite` instead.

Comment: @Eli: In my tests `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` *are* read-only (tested on Chrome8, FF3.6 and IE8). Using `1/0` works fine but it won't be so obvious to maintainers of your code what you're actually trying to test for. I agree that using `isFinite` is almost always the better way to do things -- that's why I mentioned it in my answer -- but only the OP can decide whether it meets their requirements.

Comment: They're not read-only (read: *non-configurable*), they're just accessors with getters but no setters. You can redefine them with `Object.defineProperty` and `__defineGetter__`. `Infinity`, on the other hand, *is* non-configurable in strict mode.

Comment: Is this the only case where it's worth to use == instead of ===? What happens behind the scene when I use === to compare max double against Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY? (it returns false, of course).

Comment: I would suggest to use javascript triple equals when checking for Infinity.

Ex
result === Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || result === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
  Instead of
result == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || result == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY

Answer (score 18):

In `ES6`, The [`Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) method determines whether the passed value is a finite number.

```
Number.isFinite(Infinity);  // false
Number.isFinite(NaN);       // false
Number.isFinite(-Infinity); // false

Number.isFinite(0);         // true
Number.isFinite(2e64);      // true
```

Comment: [Accessible](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isfinite.asp) from ECMAScript 1

Answer (score 10):

A simple `n === n+1` or `n === n/0` works:

```
function isInfinite(n) {
  return n === n/0;
}
```

Be aware that the native `isFinite()` coerces inputs to numbers. `isFinite([])` and `isFinite(null)` are both `true` for example.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. `n === n+1` evaluates to true for all numbers larger than 2^53, i.e., 1e30. The division hack works, even for NaN and -Infinity. However, LukeH's answer gives you waaaay more readable code.

Comment: @tglas Why is the plus like that? Glad the division is solid. IMO my code is more readable and more inclusive because math is more universal than words.

Comment: Because IEEE 64bit floats have 53 significant binary digits (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 ), so `n+1` cannot be represented and is subject to rounding. Well, even integers are affected by rounding errors. Btw, I don't think that your code is "math-proof", just try `n === n/-0`. When completing the reals with +/-inf, your limit is not well-defined unless the underlying zero sequence is assumed to be positive.

Comment: Thanks @tglas I'll always love that JavaScript can divide by zero :)

Answer (score 6):

## Perform the plain ol’ comparison:

```js
(number === Infinity || number === -Infinity)
```

or to save several characters at the expense of a function call:

```js
Math.abs(number) === Infinity
```

### The rationale for this

1. `!(Number.isFinite(number))` breaks on `NaN` inputs.
2. `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` can be redefined; they are [*configurable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).
3. `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are read-only in [the *strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).
4. It is such an elegant solution that is the shortest in both code length and execution time.

---

### Code golf

Given that `typeof n` is `"number"`, you could also do this, but please do not because it's ugly:

```
(n+"").at(-1)=="y"
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually n === n + 1 will work for numbers bigger than 51 bit, e.g.

```
1e16 + 1 === 1e16; // true
1e16 === Infinity; // false
```

Comment: This should be a comment on ryanve's answer.

Comment: “work” is misleading. Say “also evaluates to `true`.”

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) for a variety of *defensive coding* reasons as well as readability.  ES6 `Number.isFinite` is great and does not have issues with non-numeric values, but if ES6 isn't possible, you already have lodash, or want briefer code: [_.isFinite](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isFinite)

```
_.isFinite(Infinity); // false
_.isFinite(NaN); // false
_.isFinite(-Infinity); // false

_.isFinite(null); // false
_.isFinite(3); // true
_.isFinite('3'); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

I've ran into a scenario that required me to check if the value is of the `NaN` or `Infinity` type but pass strings as valid results. Because many text strings will produce false-positive `NaN`, I've made a simple solution to circumvent that:

```
  const testInput = input => input + "" === "NaN" || input + "" === "Infinity";
```

The above code converts values to strings and checks whether they are strictly equal to NaN or Infinity (you'll need to add another case for negative infinity).

So:

```
testInput(1/0); // true
testInput(parseInt("String")); // true
testInput("String"); // false
```

Comment: This post does not really deal with the actual question here and would've been better as a comment under the accepted answer. The OP is about numbers and infinity, not strings and `NaN`s, etc.

Comment: You're probably right, @code_dredd - the anecdote isn't relevant. But the solution still works: it can detect the infinity number - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's beside the point. There's already an answer that shows how to do this _correctly_. What you have "works" simply because the language itself does silly things and is inconsistent with how it manages types. Please save yourself from writing hack code like this.

Comment: Would it make you happier if I used `toString()` instead? Feel free to downvote or state reasons how this could yield inconsistent results or why exactly this method isn't recommended. So far, I still feel it adds an option for whoever's looking for an answer and there aren't any concrete reasons why this is dangerous, unstable, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **isFinite** in window, `isFinite(123)`:

You can write a function like:

```
function isInfinite(num) {
 return !isFinite(num);
}
```

And use like:

```
isInfinite(null); //false
isInfinite(1); //false
isInfinite(0); //false
isInfinite(0.00); //false
isInfinite(NaN); //true
isInfinite(-1.797693134862316E+308); //true
isInfinite(Infinity); //true
isInfinite(-Infinity); //true
isInfinite(+Infinity); //true
isInfinite(undefined); //true
```

You can also `Number.isFinit`e which also check if the value is Number too and is more accurate for checking `undefined` and `null` etc...

Or you can **polyfill** it like this:

```
Number.isFinite = Number.isFinite || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}
```