# JS - Turn Infinity Result into 0

Tags: javascript, infinity

I have a series of JS calculations that show `Infinity` depending on user choices.  How does one stop the value `Infinity` appearing and, for example, show `0.0` instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724555/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-evaluates-to-infinity

Answer (score 15):

How about this:

```
value = isFinite(value) ? value : 0.0;
```