# WebGL isinf function

Tags: floating-point, webgl

How do I check if a `float` is infinite in WebGL?

Both of these seems to work for me:

```
bool isinf(float n) {
    // one is actually required, without it n > inf if n is infinite
    // assuming n is infinite, using just inf = 1.0 / 0.0, results in n > inf
    float one = 1.0;
    float inf = one / 0.0;
    return abs(n) == inf;
}

bool isinf2(float n) {
    float small_inf = 1.0 / 0.0;
    return abs(n) > small_inf;
}
```

Is there a more standard way of doing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a number evaluates to infinity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724555/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-evaluates-to-infinity)

Comment: The first thing pops into my head is, "Would it be better to just check if the number is very, very large, larger than you reasonably expect?" Checking for infinite smells (maybe) like shorthand for a more general question...

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is not JavaScript, this is WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

I would put infinity in a constant:

```
const float inf = 1.0/0.0;

bool isinf(float n){
    return abs(n) == inf;
}
```