# Check if number is infinite as short as possible

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to find if my result is a number from 1 to 100, not infinite, but sometimes i have that  result. How i can check if result in infinite.

I know i can do it using if statement

```
x =Math.floor(1/1)
if(x == 1/0){
return 0}
else{
return x}
```

But i need it on one line

```
x =Math.floor(1/1)(1/0 ? "0" : x);
```

I try that but i have a error... what i missing?
I need that because i use it for loop statement and have around 500 numbers to sort and calculate... but without that check sometimes i have infinite result..

Anyone can help?

Comment: Instead of adding a workaround you should fix the problem. And why _"But i need it on one line"_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a number evaluates to infinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724555/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-evaluates-to-infinity)

Comment: If you have to use this in a lot of places, the solution isn't really "I need shorter code". Extract the logic into a function or even fix the problem so you don't have to do the check.

Comment: Maybe you should figure out why you have Infinity and fix that?

Comment: because sometimes i have 0 input. I use ajax call to get object from API, after that i have to sort everything, main elements from object i working on are exam results for each topic, so if someone did not make test yet he will have 0 (there is 220 exams). Thats why sometimes i will have infinite output. Already have 7 loots each as nested. less code = less file weight, less file = faster output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite):

```js
let x = Math.floor(1/1);
console.log(Number.isFinite(x)? x :0);

console.log(1/0 === Infinity);
console.log(1/0 === -Infinity); //fails for -Infinity
console.log(-1/0 === -Infinity); //number has to be -ve for this to work

//Takes care of both -Infinity and Infinity
console.log(`Number.isFinite() for -Infinity ${Number.isFinite(-Infinity)}`);
console.log(`Number.isFinite() for Infinity ${Number.isFinite(Infinity)}`);

//Returns false for NaN, null and undefined
console.log(`Number.isFinite() for NaN ${Number.isFinite(NaN)}`);
console.log(`Number.isFinite() for null ${Number.isFinite(null)}`);
console.log(`Number.isFinite() for undefined ${Number.isFinite(undefined)}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity#Description)

```js
console.log((1/0)=== Infinity)
console.log((1/10)=== Infinity)
```